# #1062 - Duplicate entry 0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

```
INSERT INTO `crm_customer` (`customerid`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `address`, 
  `telephoneno`, `companyname`, `fax`, `comments`, `countryid`, `statename`, 
  `cityname`, `emailaddress`, `zipcode`, `dateofbirth`, `unsubscribe`) 
VALUES ('0', 'jhghjgfk', 'kghjkj', 'hjkghjgh', '8776785', 'hjghjkgyjk', 
     '457665', 'jghjgfhj', '0', 'ghjgfjgf', 'gjgfhj', 'ghjgfhjgfj', 
     '764574576', '2017-03-13', '')
```

I'm getting error as `#1062 - Duplicate entry 0' for key 'PRIMARY'

---

[image: Schematics of table]

Answer (score 2):

If you have an auto increment column you don't need  the value for key primary  .. assuming you key primary is customerid you should use:

```
    INSERT INTO `crm_customer` ( `firstname`, `lastname`, `address`, 
  `telephoneno`, `companyname`, `fax`, `comments`, `countryid`, `statename`, 
  `cityname`, `emailaddress`, `zipcode`, `dateofbirth`, `unsubscribe`) 
VALUES ( 'jhghjgfk', 'kghjkj', 'hjkghjgh', '8776785', 'hjghjkgyjk', 
     '457665', 'jghjgfhj', '0', 'ghjgfjgf', 'gjgfhj', 'ghjgfhjgfj', 
     '764574576', '2017-03-13', '')
```

Simply avoid the column name and value in the corresponding part of the `insert`.

Or, you can use it in column name list but with `null` value:

```
    INSERT INTO `crm_customer` (`customerid`,  `firstname`, `lastname`, `address`, 
  `telephoneno`, `companyname`, `fax`, `comments`, `countryid`, `statename`, 
  `cityname`, `emailaddress`, `zipcode`, `dateofbirth`, `unsubscribe`) 
VALUES ( null, 'jhghjgfk', 'kghjkj', 'hjkghjgh', '8776785', 'hjghjkgyjk', 
     '457665', 'jghjgfhj', '0', 'ghjgfjgf', 'gjgfhj', 'ghjgfhjgfj', 
     '764574576', '2017-03-13', '')
```

And, if you don't have auto increment add it:

```
 ALTER TABLE crm_customer MODIFY COLUMN customerid INT auto_increment
```

Comment: **Note:** If you define it in the field list, you can also put the value as `NULL` and it will have the same effect.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ   correct  ..  asnwer  updated  with your suggestion too

Comment: @scaisEdge i put ur code  ...now i got error like dis......#1048 - Column 'customerid' cannot be null

Comment: @Diwakaryadav   .. update you question and add your table schema

Comment: @scaisEdge dude i have put the image of table schemaa in the original post....just check it out....and tell me what is the problem

Comment: I have update the answer  with the command for create auto increment ... hope is useful +

Answer (score 0):

I assume `customerid` is your primary key and you are trying to make duplicate entry for the same customerid.

Try this

```
INSERT INTO `crm_customer` ( `firstname`, `lastname`, `address`, 
  `telephoneno`, `companyname`, `fax`, `comments`, `countryid`, `statename`, 
  `cityname`, `emailaddress`, `zipcode`, `dateofbirth`, `unsubscribe`) 
VALUES ('jhghjgfk', 'kghjkj', 'hjkghjgh', '8776785', 'hjghjkgyjk', 
     '457665', 'jghjgfhj', '0', 'ghjgfjgf', 'gjgfhj', 'ghjgfhjgfj', 
     '764574576', '2017-03-13', '');
```

And if customerid is not autoincremented set, then set it by,

```
ALTER TABLE crm_customer AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

This will work if and only if you already have primary key in your table.

Answer (score 0):

you have to auto increment primary key then your error will be solve.
suppose we have a person table

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
);*
```

> `emphasized text`

  *